# Image is not storing in mysql database via php

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

I am trying to upload image and store it in mysql database through php. but no image is storing in database.

```
<form action="" method="get" name="frmPostImage" class="box" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>City:</b></td>
            <td>
                <select name="cityid">
                    <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT cityid, cityname, countryname
        FROM $t_cities ct
            INNER JOIN $t_countries c ON ct.countryid = c.countryid
        ORDER BY c.pos, ct.pos";
                    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
                    {
                        echo "<option value=\"$row[cityid]\"";
                        if ($row['cityid'] == $_REQUEST['cityid']) echo " selected";
                        echo ">$row[countryname] > $row[cityname]</option>";
                    }

                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b><?php echo $lang['POSTIMG_IMAGE_TITLE']; ?>:</b><span class="marker">*</span></td>
            <td><input name="imgtitle" type="text" id="imgtitle" size="55" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo isset($data

['imgtitle']); ?>"><br><img
                    src="images/spacer.gif"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><b><?php echo $lang['POSTIMG_IMAGE_FILE']; ?>:</b><span class="marker">*</span></td>
            <td><input name="img" type="file" size="45"><br><img src="images/spacer.gif"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><b><?php echo $lang['POSTIMG_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION']; ?>:</b></td>
            <td><textarea name="imgdesc" type="text" rows="5" cols="54"><?php echo $data['imgdesc']; ?></textarea><br><img 

src="images/spacer.gif"></td>
            <td> <input type="hidden" name="do" value="save"><button type="submit">Go</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

and following code to store it into database.

```
$expiry = time()+($expire_images_after*24*60*60);
        $expiry_dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $expiry);
        $city = $_REQUEST['cityid'];
    // Temporary file name stored on the server 
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];  

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $t_imgs
                SET imgtitle = '$_GET[imgtitle]',
                    imgfilename = '$tmpName',
                    imgdesc = '$_GET[imgdesc]',
                    postername = '$data[postername]',
                    cityid = '$city',
                    ip = '$ip',
                    verified = '1',
                    enabled = '1',
                    createdon = NOW(),
                    expireson = '$expiry_dt',
                    timestamp = NOW()"; 

         mysql_query($sql) or die($sql.mysql_error());

        if (mysql_affected_rows())
        {
            // Get ID
            $sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM $t_imgs";
            list($imgid) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));

        }
    }    

    ?>
<h2><?php echo $lang['POST_IMAGE_SUCCESS']; ?></h2>
```

i am able to store every other value except the image. tried different combination but nothing worked. Guide  me...:)

Comment: Hi, sorry, but this calls for basic debugging first. Where exactly does the code fail? Is `$_FILES` ever filled? (Do `print_r($_FILES)` to find out.) Does the database query ever actually work? Use `mysql_error()` to find out. etc. etc....

Comment: i did print_r($_FILES). Its showing Array ( ).  ???????

Comment: Do as Pekka suggested. Read the array which is outputted, check the contents of $tmpName and then you will be able to narrow down the problem. It looks like your image variable is empty, therefore you shoul rather investigate your $_FILES than your SQL

Comment: the array length is 0....its not reading image file.??????????

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be issues with mysql statement:
instead  $sql = "INSERT INTO $t_imgs SET imgtitle

you should probably use  $sql = "INSERT INTO $t_imgs values (imgtitle, ...);

check here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: i  didnt check it because i am getting every other value in db except image.

Comment: ok .. as @promilpandey suggested - try to find out what is the output of $_FILES